# Oven pilot making high pitched noise (when off)

Tags: oven, noise

There is a high pitched noise that is coming from my oven. I have pinpointed that the noise is coming from the oven pilot light, and it is most audible when the oven is off.

When the oven is off, the sound is a high pitched tone, around 4200 Hz. I recorded a sample of what it sounds like, you can listen here:

https://clyp.it/gohbjvhx

If I gently blow on the pilot light, I can hear the pitch changing slightly or go in and out.

If I turn the oven on, the sound seems to go away, or at least gets quieter and lower pitched.

What could this be?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's really hard to believe that a flame could produce that high a pitch. Have you tried blowing it out? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same situation a number of years ago with the pilot on a gas furnace. Since the furnace was next to a bedroom it was very irritating at night.
The solution: The gas pressure to the pilot needs to be reduced slightly. Locate the gas shutoff valve for the stove. Lower the pressure of the gas to the pilot by slightly closing the valve. You shouldn't have to turn it very much. I'm betting that will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the issue. I lowered the pressure slightly and the noise went away. Thanks!